# Network problems setting up an Ubuntu server in VirtualBox

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

Before I get into my problem I would like to start with what I am trying to accomplish in case my approach is non-optimal.

I want to setup a virtual environment that mirrors our production environment as closely as possible. This will consist of a web server, a database server, and a file server, all on the same network. I want to use this as an integration environment to test new features, and their deployment scripts, before we release them.

The VMs need to be able to talk to each other within the virtual network and have Internet access. My host machine must have the ability to connect to these devices from within the virtual network.

My approach is to use Vagrant to spin up multiple copies of a base VirtualBox VM and then configure them appropriately.

I have installed Ubunu 12.04 64-bit server in a VM. On the networking side Adapter is is set to NAT. Adapter 2 is "Host-only Adapter" attached to vboxnet0.

vboxnet0 has the following configuration

```
IPv4 Address: 192.168.56.1
IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
ipv6 Network Mask Length: 64
Enable Server: Checked
Server Address: 192.168.56.100
Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
Lower Address Bound: 192.168.56.101
Upper Address Bound: 192.168.56.254
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0 eth1
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.56.105
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.56.1
  network 192.168.56.0
  broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

The machine appears to have internet access. I can wget resources, and I can ping 192.168.56.105 from my host. However I am running in to some problems.

If I apt-get update it start pulling checking.

```
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
...
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
...
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am also unable to bring down eth1.

```
vm@base:~$ sudo ifdown eth1
ifdown: interface eth1 not configured
```